# USB to PS2 Convertor

Tags: usb, ps2

We are using USB keyboard it is working with PC. We are using Same keyboard with our microcontroller kit with USB to PS2 convertor also it is working. I wanted to know that, whether USB signals D+ and D- are similar to PS2 signals Clock and Data??

Comment: PS2 signals (CLK and DATA) and USB (D+, D-) are very different.  Your converter probably has a processor in it to handle both protocols.  Both standards are freely available online if you want to know more.  A full answer would be a book making this question off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

No, they're completely different.

Keyboards which can work with both usually have special systems to detect which one they've been plugged into.

Comment: Thanks for your off the mark reply.
What you stated is already known/theory. Our problem is:
a) USB keyboard already working with Win10 64 bit PC when inserted using USB to PS2 convertor into PS2 connector of another product (8085 kit), it works.
b) The cheap convertor consists of simply wires shorting DATA (pin 1 of PS2) to D- (USB) & Clock (pin 5 of PS2) to D+(USB).
Question is why it should work since USB & PS2 are very different.

Comment: What's with the sarcasm? The keyboard itself detects which protocol to use. Why should that not work?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not similar, they are quite a bit different.

USB has a half duplex differential pair to transfer packets of data with the host. In case of standard keyboard is 3.3V logic levels up to 12 Mbps.

PS/2 keyboard interface has two open drain wires with 5V logic levels and it transfers bits at about 20 kbps. The communication is mainly clock and data bits from keyboard to host, but as lines are bidirectional, host can inhibit the keyboard from sending by pulling clock low, and host can request transfer to keyboard (e.g to set LEDs) by pulling data low.

Some keyboards support both protocols and can detect which one to use and a passive electromechanical adapter can be used. Some only support one protocol and active USB to PS/2 adapter has to be used.

Comment: Could you expand this answer?

Comment: Thanks for your off the mark reply.
What you stated is already known/theory. Our problem is:
a) USB keyboard already working with Win10 64 bit PC when inserted using USB to PS2 convertor into PS2 connector of another product (8085 kit), it works.
b) The cheap convertor consists of simply wires shorting DATA (pin 1 of PS2) to D- (USB) & Clock (pin 5 of PS2) to D+(USB).
Question is why it should work since USB & PS2 are very different.

Comment: I already said some keyboards support both USB and PS/2 so they work with USB and PS/2 ports with simple cheap convertor. If keyboard does not work then keyboard supports only one protocol and does not work with simple convertor.